# NoData fill QGIS (alternative to nibble tool in ArcGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, nodata

I have two raster layers - one is a mastergrid, the other shows slope. I want to 'expand' my slope raster so that it covers the same extent as the mastergrid by in some way interpolating the 'missing' raster cells from the other slope values. In ArcGIS, I've done this before using the nibble tool, however this time around I need the process to be done in QGIS. I did some googling and came across the Fill nodata GDAL tool, which seemed to offer what I wanted. But when setting the slope raster as the input layer, and the mastergrid as the validity mask, the output is just the same as the input, no changes made.

What settings should I use in the tool, or is there an alternative method?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the rasters?

Comment: I don't quite get what this means "in some way interpolating the 'missing' raster cells from the other slope values". Could you add a link to a description of the nibble tool?